# Reading Scala In Example, trying to understand the philosophy behind the examples

Tags: class, scala, inheritance, methods

I am reading the Scala in Examples book and almost every example there has the following construction:

```
abstract class Stack[A] {
  def push(x: A): Stack[A] = new NonEmptyStack[A](x, this)
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def top: A
  def pop: Stack[A]
}
class EmptyStack[A] extends Stack[A] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def top = error("EmptyStack.top")
  def pop = error("EmptyStack.pop")
}
class NonEmptyStack[A](elem: A, rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def top = elem
  def pop = rest
}
```

And I have the following two interconnected questions:
1) Is it a common Scala practice to represent empty and non-empty elements as separate classes? If yes then why?
2) Why do the children both implement the same dumb ethod 'isEmpty' when it is possible and, to me, more sensible to do this in the parent class?

I would like to know the deepest of the philosophy involved here.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like that the division goes back to one of the cornerstones of the functional or, more precisely, "list-oriented" programming I have noticed long ago while briefly touching Erlang, Clojure and Lisp. So there must be a really essential meaning to this. As for the second question, then thanks to your answer I understand that it is just a too simple example to witness the whole power of such an approach.

Comment: is it common practice? Collections - perhaps, general application coding, I instead use Option. For me, both your questions have one answer - the author meant to demonstrate how inheritance and specifically abstract classes and methods could be used. isEmpty, top, pop are demoed as abstract methods and so must be implemented by inheriting classes and can have different implementations. This is just an opinion so not posting as an answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, this division can help you to answer question like: "How can I write a function that operates on stacks but fails at **compile time** if I pass it an empty stack"

Comment: There are trade-offs between implementing `isEmpty` (or similar methods) in the parent vs the children. One advantage of deferring implementation to the children is that you don't have to modify the parent's code if you wish to add a new child class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes it is common to have separate classes for empty and non-empty containers, this is generally called an algebraic data structure, however it is usually not so apparent.  For example, Scala's List has two classes, `Nil` to represent an empty list, and `::` that contains one element and another list.  So

```
List(1,2,3)
```

while usually referred to by the `List[T]` trait, is really an instance of `:: [B] (hd: B, tl: List[B])` that looks like:

```
::(1, ::(2, ::(3, Nil)))
```

2) Each class must implement the `isEmpty` method becuase if you notice, the value is different in each child class.  It simply saves some computation to figure out whether an instance of `Stack` is empty or not, since each child type already knows this at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, this is Scala's way of expressing *algebraic data types* or *discriminated unions*, common in functional programming languages. The alternative here is having just one class with optional data members (either using `Option`, which also has a subclass for empty and a subclass for non-empty, or using `null`). This forces all of your methods to have to check whether the object actually has data or not, making them more complex; using subclasses has the system's virtual method dispatch (which it is going to do anyway) do this check for you. It also forces the data present to be **consistent**; a `Stack` either has an `elem` and a `rest` (`NonEmptyStack`) or it doesn't have either (`EmptyStack`). It's not possible for it to have one but not the other (assuming no one deliberately makes a `NonEmptyStack` with a `null`, which is very rare in Scala).

The general pattern of data types being one of several cases, where each case has different data attached, is widely applicable. Having one of the cases contain *no* data is simply a trivial case of this general pattern. As a Scala programmer, using this general pattern will become familiar to you, so it seems quite natural to apply it to simple cases as well.

---

2) You'll note that **all** of the methods in each child class immediately return a value, with no further computation  (excepting the error cases, which immediately throw an exception with no further computation). This makes them very obvious and easy to understand, so long as you are used to thinking in terms of virtual method dispatch.

Furthermore, it makes them quite efficient; the **only** computation necessary to determine what each method should return is the virtual method dispatch, which the system is going to do for you anyway. To implement `isEmpty` in the parent class you would have to add some form of instance checking and branching; this is effectively just a manual form of the system's virtual method dispatch anyway!

Furtherfurthermore, and I think most importantly, the child-class implementation is more maintainable. Say you add a further specialised kind of non-empty stack (maybe you have loads of stacks with exactly 1 element and don't want to waste space storing an extra reference to the empty stack, or something). If you have branching in the parent to return answers that are different for different subclasses, you have to go and update each of them to take into account the new subclass. **And the compiler will probably not notice if you don't do this.** If you've implemented every subclass-specific behaviour in a subclass, then you just implement the methods in the new subclass.

Answer (score 2):

It looks similar to the implementation of `List`. I'm just guessing here, but the example will probably be continued in the later chapters of the book where pattern matching is explained so the implementations will be prefixed with the `case` keyword so you can match on `Stack`s as you can match on `List`s in the `case head :: tail =>` way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how would you propose to write this without an "empty" subclass? Try to write it (and remember that you can't use mutable state), and you'll see it is very hard. The only way I know of requires a private constructor.